# Terraform `local-exec` to set a local alias

Tags: shell, alias, terraform

I'm trying to set up an alias to quickly ssh into the newly created host when I create an AWS instance in [terraform](/questions/tagged/terraform). I do this by running

```
# Handy alias to quickly ssh into newly created host
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "alias sshopenldap='ssh -i ${var.key_path} ubuntu@${aws_instance.ldap_instance.public_dns}'"
}
```

When I see the output of this execution:

```
aws_instance.ldap_instance (local-exec): Executing: /bin/sh -c "alias sshopenldap='ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com'"
```

It seems to be ok, but the alias is not set. Could this be that the way the command is being run it wraps it in a new scope and not the one of the current shell? If I copy paste the command as is to the console the alias is set fine.

Is there a workaround for this?

*I'm running terraform a MacOS X Mountain Lion's terminal.*

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
# Handy alias to quickly ssh into newly created host
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "echo \"alias sshopenldap='ssh -i ${var.key_path} ubuntu@${aws_instance.ldap_instance.public_dns}'\" > script.sh && source script.sh && rm -rf source.sh"
}
```

Not sure how the quote escaping will go...

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed not possible to set an alias for the current shell in a script file, which is what your are trying to do. The only way to get out of this is to *not* run a script, but instead source it. So:

```
source somefile.sh
```

instead of executing it should do the trick.

Comment: thanks @Stephan W., I'll try it out and come back to you.